# Function guaranteed to never return the same value twice

Tags: algorithms, concurrency

This is a question I was asked at a job interview, and I can't figure out the answer they were looking for, so I'm hoping someone here might have some ideas. The goal is to write a function that is guaranteed to never return the same value twice. Assume that this function will be accessed by multiple machines concurrently.

My idea was to assign each machine a unique id and pass that value into the unique value generator function:

```
var i = 0;
function uniq(process_id, machine_id) {
   return (i += 1).toString() + machine_id + "-" + process_id;
}
```

This would avoid the fallout from race conditions since even if two or more processes read the same value for `i`, each return value is tagged a unique combination of process id and machine id. However, my interviewer didn't like this answer because bringing another machine online involves assigning it an id.

So can anybody think of another way to solve this that doesn't involve configuring each machine to have a unique id? I'd like to have an answer in case this question comes up again. Thanks.

Comment: Guaranteed in the strict sense of the word? I mean, even Guids will at some point start to repeat themselves. We may not live anymore, but guarantees .. And by the way, a process ID is [far from being unique](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/07/10112755.aspx).

Comment: On physical machines you could assume that MAC addresses are unique.

Comment: In a practical situation I'd go with a random value of sufficient size. ~120 are a common choice, at 256 bits you're clearly on the safe side (hardware errors that cause a counter to malfunction are much more likely than a 256 bit collision).

Comment: @CodesInChaos - That is a fairly terrible assumption, given that it is trivial in some operating systems to change your mac address.

Comment: On physical machines, it's simply impossible since any real-world machine is a finite state machine, and thus *must* repeat itself. Even if you convert all matter and all energy in the entire universe into one giant computer, that computer will still have only finitely many states, which means that if it runs long enough, it will at some time be in a state it was in before and thus return the same result. "Never" is an awfully long time.

Comment: "Assume that this function will be accessed by multiple machines concurrently" - honestly, this could either mean "the code runs on each machine indivually, with no communication between the machines", or "there is a central machine / central database where the function is provided for the other machines, available over the network". You should start clarifying this first.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: any physical machine has a finite lifetime and limited speed. So I think it is safe to assume the "guarantee to never return the same value twice" has only to be made for the lifetime of the system ;-)

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)**

Comment: Another idea is to use MAC address and current date, combine them each other for example convert MAC address to decimal format and add UNIX time to it.

Comment: Was it a trick question? For example, a function containing an infinite loop will never return the same value twice..

Comment: Perhaps they were looking for a programmer who asks questions about dubious requirements, rather than making assumptions and running with it :)

Comment: If the integer being output has N bits, then a value must be repeated once every value has already been handed out.  So, technically speaking it's an impossible requirement.  Practically speaking, this is just a GUID.  It also isn't stated whether the value is guessable, or whether concurrent accesses should block (which is required if you simply increment), or whether clients should partition the space.  

But just returning a big enough random number is sufficient.

Comment: When I need unique numbers that are guaranteed to be unique between machines and not be subject to reset upon reboot I use a sequence number from a database. Multiple machines can request numbers and the central database maintains uniqueness.

Comment: To everyone saying that this is an "impossible requirement" due to the pigeonhole principle: no it isn't. Simply throw an exception rather than returning a value once the function has returned all possible values in its range.

Comment: This is impossible unless you track all returned values. Also, I agree with gnat's position on this. Interview questions are designed to test your motor, not to yield definitive solutions, so these kind of questions are merely noise.

Comment: I know this question has been answered, and this comment will likely get buried, but the problem with such questions is that they are VERY subjective.  The interviewer probably hopes to hear something specific but, honestly, you have no way of knowing what that is.  I offer two suggestions for the future-- just because you can't provide the specific answers they desire for their relative questions, don't lose heart.  Second, ask questions, questions, questions.  You can't write any useful software without clear requirements.  Therefore, demand requirements from the interviewer.

Comment: `function neverReturns() { throw new Exception(); }` will never return the same value, but that's just because it never returns *any* value.

Comment: IMO this question has a very simple, straight answer: it cannot be done. Let's read the question word-by-word and the conclusion is one: there is NO function guaranteed to never return a value twice. Because whatever N you choose as the size (in bits) of the return value, after 2^N calls you will have exhausted all the possible values.

Comment: You can tell them that computers are not good in generating real random numbers, only pseudorandom. It's better to use hardware based randomization for that.

Comment: simple if you are on Linux. function uniq(process_id, machine_id,current_time). machine_id is always unique and is either in /etc/machine-id or on Ubuntu/Debian: /var/lib/dbus/machine-id

Answer (score 60):

Don't get fancy, just toss a simple (threadsafe) counter behind some communication endpoint (WCF, web service, whatever):

```
   long x = long.MinValue;
   public long ID(){
       return Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
   }
```

Yes, it will eventually overflow. Yes, it doesn't handle reboots. Yes, it's not random. Yes, someone could run this on multiple servers.

This is the simplest thing that satisfies practical requirements. Then let *them* be the ones that follow up with those problems (to make sure they understand the limitations, do they *really* think you need more than 2^64 ids), so you can then ask about what trade-offs are okay. Does it need to survive reboots? What about hard drive failure? What about nuclear war? Does it need to be random? How random?

Comment: This is a good answer, because interviewer never ask questions to get a straight answer. They want you to give an answer where you can justify your decisions. If you understand the domain, nearly any answer will be suitable if you can justify it.

Comment: How is this supposed to work if the code runs *on different machines* (so obviously in different processes)? Each process will have a different copy of `x`. And I think without an explanation about the kind of interlocking mechanism you have in mind, this answer is pretty vague.

Comment: @DocBrown "accessed by multiple Machines concurrecntly" seems to imply that multiple machines **access** a single function on a single server. Otherwise it should be worded "Multiple machines will run a copy of this function at the same time"

Comment: @Falco: the supposed solution of the OP seems to imply the opposite. Nethertheless, as I wrote in a comment below the original question, that is exactly the thing to clarify first. And the supposed solution in this answer aims for *multithreading*, which was not mentioned in any way in the question. If a single function in a single process on a server was meant, I expect the server infrastructure to already handle the concurrent calls to this function and sequentialize them - which means there is no need to add some kind of locking.

Comment: ... the only situation where this answer makes sense is when the server will map the concurrent request of different machines to different threads on the single server, but this kind of situation is making way to many assumptions about the infrastructure. So that's why I wrote the answer "may be wrong" (there is a slight chance it is not, but in that case, I miss an explanation about the assumptions of this answer). I also miss an explicit explanation of what kind of locking this unexplained "Interlocked" function does.

Comment: What language is this? What is `Interlocked`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I guess this is meant to be C#, and the `System.Threading.Interlocked` class, which provides atomic increments. But you could this also read as some kind of pseudo code.

Comment: @DocBrown - I expect this to be a simple function sitting behind a WCF endpoint or similar. A function that returns different values no matter where it is run from without any sort of coordination/shared state is even more impossible. I will update the answer with that clarification.

Comment: @DocBrown: I guess what I'm trying to say is that, for pseudocode, it's insufficiently clear as to what `Interlocked` does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - DocBrown is correct, it is C#, and the interlocked provides atomic increments. I've subtly edited the answer to hopefully clarify a bit.

Comment: @Telastyn: your answer is IMHO better now (assumed the OP really meant this function to be run on a single server, as a service for the other machines).

Comment: If I were the person asking I would be very unhappy with this proposal. Starting implementing something without even knowing what the requirements are is a big red flag. I would expect you to ask.

Comment: @JensG: it's only a few lines of what could be pseudo code. See it as a discussion piece, something to talk about in order to wring more detailed requirements out of them.

Comment: @JensG - *shrug* I could go on for 5+ minutes about requirements, or I could spend 10 seconds describing a potential solution and we can go from there. This is a bad interview question, and at this point I would be more interested in finding out if my interviewers/potential coworkers are competent than pleasing them.

Comment: This isn't a good approach. As a customer, if I give an unclear requirement, and the engineer goes off and builds me a solution that doesn't work, I am going to be upset that they went to work and spent my money without bothering to ask me first.

Comment: @rmayer06 - No customer is going to tell me function level specifications. If so, I'm going to stop them and then ask _what_ they really need the code to do (rather than telling me _how_ it needs to be done). That though would be entirely inappropriate in an ***interview***.

Comment: @Telastyn, I disagree, but that is my personal preference. I think all is fair in an interview, and have been told that I interview very well. You always want to ask questions on requirements that drive major assumptions or major cost (see my answer below).

Answer (score 25):

If I were asked that question, and they made it clear that it has to be unique across reboots and across different machines, I'd give them a function that calls into the standard mechanism for creating a new GUID, whatever that happens to be in the language being used.

Comment: The problem with v4 GUIDs is that they're only very likely unique, not guaranteed unique. Not a big issue in practice, but not satisfy the requirements if the interviewer takes them literally.

Comment: In particular, if the standard GUID mechanism doesn't meet the interviewer's requirements, then tease out the differences in requirements between the interviewer and an ordinary user of GUIDs. A *sensible* interviewer asking this kind of question ("how do you do <some generally-known standard thing perhaps with a slight variation from the usual requirements>") should expect very different kinds of answer from candidates who know about the state of the art for GUIDs and candidates who are inventing something from scratch.

Comment: This is probably the simplest answer, assuming flexible requirements.

Comment: +1 because this is basically the problem that guids solve. Producing a duplicate Guid, no matter its format, is the most difficult lottery on the planet. Apparently many people don't have a sense for the exponential unlikeliness of collisions.

Comment: Oh, and if you offer the "use a standard function" answer to any such question, expect a follow-up question "and how is the standard function implemented?". To which you might very well answer "I don't know, but I'd definitely look it up rather than trying to invent something", which is a completely accurate answer that completely fails to maintain the expected suspension of disbelief in interview conditions, that you'd *ever* do *anything* important without researching it first ;-)

Comment: @usr Although if we speak about guarantees in a formal way, unlikeliness is not relevant. Unless one explicitly specifies the guarantee as with regards to a specific level of improbability.

Comment: @Alex you have a point there. On the other hand I'd be willing to make this uniqueness assumption in production code and in an interview. I'd wait for the interviewer to correct me on that and simply offer a different solution.

Comment: @usr Sure, and I guess that we can assume that there always is at least an implicit assumption to improbability in this, unless the context is clearly related to formal logic.

Answer (score 22):

The interviewer said the method will be called concurrently, not in parallel; just return the date/time down to as many decimal places as you can.

Why is everyone over-thinking this?  You'll be dead a long time before any finiteness is expended and you don't have a chance of a collision.

If you're worried about it returning the same time, add a delay for the smallest amount of measurable time.

If you're worried about setting a clock back for daylight savings time (experiencing 1 time twice), add a constant to the time the second time you experience it.

Comment: Or just return UTC time regardless of the requestors timezone.  As UTC is not localised then it wont be affected by DST changes.

Comment: System.currentTimeNanos() :-)

Comment: Unless you're returning the date & time in a human-readable format, your value shouldn't have any timezone information inside of it anyway.

Comment: The smallest amount of time is still going to produce collisions if called frequently/concurrently enough. It will also produce collisions due to clock synchronization drift, malicious clock manipulation, and if you're not careful - daylight savings.

Comment: Very creative, at least. Relying on a clock that is going to be adjusted every now and then is still not such a great idea, IMHO. The offset will not save you from collisions.

Comment: @Telastyn: The resolution of context-switching in modern CPUs is _at least_ 1ms, last I checked. As for clock manipulation, if you're not using the monotonic clock then that's your own fault :P As it is if you've exposed yourself to DST (wtf) as explored above

Comment: @Telastyn What do you mean "concurrently enough".  It sounds like you're talking about parallelism, not concurrency.  A simple lock+delay would would work fine.

Comment: @Brian - I mean that (as I understand it), multi-proc machines can return the same exact time (even CPU time) if you're unlucky enough to trigger both calls at the same time. I remember a few games I had needed to be forced to use one proc because the calls would occasionally go backwards in time if they swapped processor, causing the simulation bits to explode. I don't see how a lock+delay would work at all.

Comment: Why not take the time as a string and append a random GUID? If the requirement is just uniqueness, there's no harm in a bit of padding.

Comment: If you want to return the time down to the most precise unit we can measure, why not use the suggestion @Falco posted and use the current nanosecond time? Even the fastest processes take a few nanoseconds to compute, so it will never return the same value twice until it overflows, at which point it's still unlikely that any two machines will have gotten the same ID.

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow == DateTime.UtcNow` is almost always true. This is a not a good source of unique values.

Comment: -1 basically because of what Telastyn & usr said: The clock in a computer likely isn't accurate enough (or set up accurately enough by the OS) to guarantee that any two reads of the time will yield a different time. Under Windows at least, you sometimes don't even get millisecond accuracy.

Comment: +1 Even if this is not always practical, it is the only solution that conceptually establishes a formal guarantee, relying on a infinitely large variable instead of random probability, assuming that we get the time from a universal and perfect service. Which of course is unreasonable practically, but whatever.

Comment: -1 As already mentioned, collisions are not prevented and delay without locking won't do anything

Comment: @stakx I didn't say what os this is.. Let's say it's on a VXWorks machine with a highly accurate clock.   Funny how everyone likes their own assumptions best.

Comment: Fine, everyone, add a 5 day delay to the function and we'll never collide.  It will take 5 day for 2 calls of it to return, but problem solved on my end.

Comment: @brian: Indeed you did not say what OS this was, which is also why you cannot give an answer based on the assumption that you *might* be talking about a VXWorks computer with a highly accurate clock. If you compare the speed of a computer clock with the processor speed, I'd say it's likely that the processor is generally the faster. If the processor supports multitasking OSes, there's therefore a distinct possibility that two processes will read the clock at the same time. My comment above was meant as a general answer in that respect; the Windows OS reference was just for illustration.

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, you will want to ask the interviewer two questions.

---

Question 1.

whether the interviewer ***expects*** one or more "central machines" to be used to assign some unique numbers, or blocks of unique numbers.

---

Question 2.

Whether the interviewer ***expects*** a mechanism for collision detection, or instead  accept the calculated risk of a minuscule chance of collision without explicitly detecting them.

There is also the defense-in-depth approach, in which one incorporates some part of user-ID into the randomness (thus, not entirely random). The chance that the same user encounters a collision within the content created by that same user is therefore lowered.

---

There is an implicit question 3, ...

But it is one you'll have to gauge yourself without asking, because it is extremely impolite to ask your interviewer.

Whether the interviewer assumes the knowledge of probability, risk, and some simple techniques employed in cryptographic and information-security systems.

The first kind of knowledge ensures you're not trying to convince a non-scientific person into accepting a scientific concept they won't accept.

The second kind of knowledge ensures that you addresses concerns which are in addition to mere probability. In other words, how to defend against "assailants" who want to intentionally break your randomization scheme, by manipulating the machine(s) or their virtual hosts to force two machines to generate the same value.

---

Why ask.

The reason is that if the interviewer expects it one way or another, trying to answer with the opposite approach will never make the interviewer happy.

The deeper reason is that some people do not like the idea of say, a `1.0e-20` chance of failing. (I'll try not to stir up philosophical or religious arguments here.)

---

First of all the "namespace" of random numbers are made into a hierarchy, with certain number of bits allocated to one source of randomization, and the other number of bits allocated to some other ways, etc.

The centralized approach relies on some central authority to uniquely assign the first level of bits. Then, the other machines can fill the rest of the bits.

There are several decentralized approaches:

- Just generate random numbers as good as one could, and accept the practically-zero chance of failing justified by calculations.
- Use cryptographic means of generating random values from deterministic source, say, an incrementing values.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. The others are solutions without requirements.

Comment: Remarking on your third question - it seems that competence is a safe assumption, or at least an irrelevant one. If a company didn't provide a competent interviewer, there will likely be larger flaws to the selection process. If they did, then he/she will appreciate the questions.

Comment: Why couldn't "question 3" be addressed by asking something along the lines of, "Do we need truly guaranteed uniqueness or just a very, very low probability of collisions?" and, "How secure does this need to be? Do we need to assume an attacker will be trying to break the mechanism? What kinds of attacks are we concerned about?" Answers to those questions should clarify whether the asker understands these issues and what they expect.

Answer (score 12):

So, keeping in mind that this is an interview question and not an actual real-life scenario, I believe the correct approach (and probably what the interviewer is looking for) is to ask a clarifying question, or to write "It can't be done" and move on. Here's why.

### What the Interviewer Asks:

> Write a function that is guaranteed to never return the same value twice. Assume that this function will be accessed by multiple machines concurrently.

### What the Interviewer Needs:

> Does this candidate effectively evaluate requirements and seek additional input when required?

### Never Assume.

When an engineer is handed a requirement (via a SOW or Specification or some other requirements document), some are self-evident, and others are totally unclear. This is a perfect example of the latter. As the previous answers have shown, there is no way to respond to this requirement without making several major assumptions either (a) as to the nature of the question or (b) as to the nature of the system, because the requirement cannot be met as-written (it is impossible).

Most of the answers make one attempt or another at solving the problem via a series of assumptions.  One specifically recommends to just get it done quickly and let the customer worry about it if it's wrong.

This is really a bad approach.  As a customer, if I give an unclear requirement, and the engineer goes off and builds me a solution that doesn't work, I am going to be upset that they went to work and spent my money without bothering to ask me first. That sort of cavalier decision-making  demonstrates a lack of teamwork, inability to think critically, and poor judgement.  It can lead to any manner of negative consequences, including loss-of-life in a safety critical system.

### Why Ask the Question?

The point if this exercise is that it is expensive and time-consuming to build to ambiguous requirements. In the OP's case, you have been given an impossible task. Your first action should be to ask for clarification - what is it that is required? What degree of uniqueness is needed? What happens if a value is non-unique? The answer to these questions could be the difference between several weeks of time and a few minutes.  In the real world, one of the biggest drivers of cost in complex systems (including many software systems) is unclear and poorly-understood requirements. This leads to expensive and time-consumig bugs, re-designs, customer and team frustration, and embarassing media coverage if the project is large enough.

### What Happens When You Assume?

Given my background in the aerospace industry, and due to the highly visible nature of aerospace failures, I like to bring up examples from this domain to illustrate important points.  Let's examine a pair of failed Mars missions - the Mars Climate Orbiter and Mars Polar Lander.  Both missions failed due to software problems -- because engineers made invalid assumptions due, in part, to unclear and poorly-communicated requirements.

**Mars Climate Orbiter** - this case is typically cited as what happens when NASA tries to convert English to Metric units. However, that is an overly simplistic and poor representation of what really transpired. True, there was a conversion problem, but it was due to poorly-communicated requirements in the design phase and an improper verification/validation scheme. Furthermore, when two different engineers noticed the problem because it was obvious from flight trajectory data, they didn't raise the issue to the proper level because they assumed it was a transmission error. Would the mission ops team have been made aware of the issue, there was adequate time to correct it and save the mission. In this case, there was an impossible logical condition that was not recognized for what it was, leading to costly mission failure.

**Mars Polar Lander** - this case is a little less well-known, but possibly more embarassing due to its temporal proximity to the Mars Climate Orbiter failure. In this mission, the software controlled the thruster-assisted descent of the rocket into the Martian surface. At a point 40 meters above the surface, the legs of the lander deployed in preparation for landing. There was also a sensor on the legs that detected motion (to signal when they had impacted) to tell the software to shut off the engine. NASA's best guess as to what happened (because there are multiple possibile failures and incomplete data) is that random vibrations in the legs due to their deployment simultaneously and improperly triggered the shutdown mechanism 40m above the surface, resulting in the crash and destruction of the $110M spacecraft. This possibility was raised in development, but was never addressed.  Ultimately, the software team made invalid assumptions about how this code needed to run (one such assumption is that a spurious signal would be too short-lived to be picked up, despite tests showing the contrary), and those assumptions were never questioned until after the fact.

### Additional Considerations

Interviewing and evaluating people is a tricky business. There are several dimensions of a candidate that an interviewer may wish to explore, but one of the most important is an idividual's ability to think critically. For a variety of reasons, not the least of which is that critical thinking is poorly-defined, we have a very difficult time evaluating critical thinking skills.

As an engineering instructor, one of my favorite ways to evaluate a student's ability to think critically was to ask a somewhat ambiguous question. The sharper students would pick up on the question's faulty premise, note it, and either answer given the premise or decline to answer altogether. Typically, I would ask a question similar to the following:

> You pick up a drawing from your stack of work. The drawing contains a variety of different callouts, but the most important points to a horizontal surface and says "Perfectly flat". The surface is 5" wide by 16" long, and the part is made of aluminum. How will you machine the part to create this feature?

(By the way, you would be shocked at how often such a poor specification appears in the workplace.)

I expect that students will recognize that it is not possible to create a perfect feature, and that they will state this in their answer. I typically would award a bonus point if they say they will go back to the designer and ask for clarification before making the part. If a student proceeds to tell me how they are going to achieve .001 planarity or some other made up value, I award zero points.  This helps me make a point to my students that they need to be thinking of the bigger picture.

### Bottom Line

If I am interviewing an engineer (or similar profession), I am looking for someone who can think critically and question what has been placed in front of him. I want someone who asks the question "Does this make sense?"  .

It does not make sense to ask for a perfectly flat part, because there is no such thing as perfect. It does not make sense to ask for a function that never returns a duplicate value, because it is impossible to make such a guarantee. In programming, we often hear the phrase "garbage in, garbage out." If you are handed garbage for requirements, it is your ethical responsibility to stop and ask whatever question helps you elicit the true intent. If I'm interviewing a candidate, and I give them an unclear requirement, I am going to expect clarification questions.

Answer (score 5):

Guaranteeing uniqueness is difficult because computers do not have infinitely-large variables. No real-world Turing machine can.

The way I see it there are two problems here, and both have well-established solutions.

- Concurrency. Multiple machines may need a value at the same time. Thankfully, modern CPUs have concurrency built-in and some languages provide developer-friendly facilities to take advantage of this.
- Uniqueness. While impossible to guarantee uniqueness, we can have arbitrarily-large variables which can hold values so large that a real-world system would have a *very* difficult time exhausting all of the unique values

Here is my solution in Java:

```
public class Foo {
  private static BigInteger value = BigInteger.ZERO;
  private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  public static BigInteger nextValue() {
    try {
      lock.lock();
      value = value.add(BigInteger.ONE);
      return value;
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

BigInteger is an arbitrary-size integer type. It can grow to hold values that are quite large, even if not infinite. The lock ensures concurrency, so the same value cannot be returned twice by two simultaneous requests serviced by separate threads.

Comment: I think the assumption that the code will only be used for less than five hundred years is a valid assumption.  If you simply return increasing values in 64bit storage, you're fine for quite a while.  At 1 call per us, in 584555 years.

Comment: At least in Java, that is 2^63 values (so half that long). Still longer than the human race will likely exist given our tendency to kill each other. Regardless, I took a more theoretical approach. Realistically, 64 (or 63) bits should be enough.

Comment: @Snowman: WHAT?!? Your solution is only valid for 250K years?!?!? NEXT CANDIDATE!!!!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would expose the function via a port on the server; to call the function, the requesting machine requests a connection and is granted one, while at the same time being allocated an identifying code (sequential number for simplicity). Whenever a message is sent to the port requesting the unique value, the value is generated by concatenating the MD5 hash of the current date and time with the MD5 hash of the identifying code.

If they want a more bulletproof solution they would have to specify their actual requirements rather than being all vague about things.

Answer (score -1):

```
string uniq(string machine_id) 
{
   static long u = long.MinValue;
   Interlocked.Increment(ref u);

   //Time stamp with millisecond precison
   string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

   return machine_id + "-" + timestamp + "-" + u;
}
```

In the above way we can make sure that return value is different even if there are restart or even if called simultaneous from different machines.

Comment: Programmers is [about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) conceptual questions and answers are expected to explain things. Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Comment: Thanks gnat for pointing it out, will take care to explain the solution from next time