# Generating billions of Unique random number

Tags: java, algorithms, random

I recently attended an interview. In that I had to solve the issue for generating an billions of random unique number. 
For example method signature is as below :

```
public Iterator<Long> generate(final long N, final Random rand){

}
```

The returned iterator should contain N unique random numbers.
This method will be tested against 10billion as N and you have only 128 MB JVM memory.
How would you do it.? 
I came with below answer which he said that there might me 1 or 2 instances that number might repeat. How would I guarantee. For eg: Birthday paradox problem.
My solution:

```
public Iterator<Long> generate(long N, Random rand) {
            LongStream stream = rand.longs(N);
            return stream.iterator();
}
```

Unfortunalty I did not go through an interview process since it was short time. But still I want to know how would we handle 10 billion unique random generation efficiently.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Comment: Can you use disk?

Comment: Do they need to be cryptographically secure, or is pseudo random ok?

Comment: While it might be possible to create such an algorithm (but I highly doubt it), I wouldn't expect anyone to create it without extensive research and trial-and-error. Especially if you want to guarantee both 10 billion numbers and non-repeating requirement.

Comment: use GUIDs is the simple answer. But I have a feeling the question is about hashing and indexes.

Comment: I'd use a 64 bit blockcipher, like 3des or blowfish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function guaranteed to never return the same value twice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263595/function-guaranteed-to-never-return-the-same-value-twice)

Comment: Depends how 'random' they need these values to be - but simply hashing or XOR'ing a simple counter might suffice

Answer (score 2):

These are usually trick questions. A way to think about the trick implied is to see that the RAM you are allowed- 128mb- is roughly 1 billion bits. 10 billion numbers can be seen as 1 billion groups of 10 numbers. So, to generate a unique random sequence of 10 billion numbers, think about it as 1 billion non-overlapping groups of 10 unique numbers.

Use the 1 billion bit data structure as a big set of flags to track which groups of numbers have been generated. Generate 10 random numbers at a time, using them to pick specific numbers within a specific group of numbers.

You can use randomness to pick which group to generate as well; that becomes expensive as you get to the end, so better to have an algorithm for traversing through the group space. Generate numbers from a few specific groups at a time, then randomize the sequence by which those numbers are returned. There are many variations on this theme, of course, and different ways to meet different standards of randomness.

Comment: "to generate a unique random sequence of 10 billion digits," I don't think that's what the OP's problem calls for.

Comment: sorry, typo: s/digit/number/